# Google Maps V3 API Key Invalid - but my personal dev key works

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I've recently been doing development upgrading our maps to v3 and during development I was using my own personal key. Everything was working fine. When it was time to go to production I had someone generate a key through the company's google account and now it doesn't work. I've sat next to them making sure they were generating a browser key, and I'm pretty sure the domains are correct under the "Referrer's" section matching both:
*.mydomain.com/*
mydomain.com/*

I've verified that we are using Key for browser apps.

I've verified that the Google Maps API v3 is turned ON via the services panel. Everything is identical to the way I was doing it with my key. I think the only difference is that they've enabled Billing on the company account where as my key doesn't. We'd like to get this moved off of my key seeing as how it's receiving more than the 25k views/day limit on my account.

When using the company API key the map loads and then very quickly I get an alert box which reads: "Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site. If you are the owner of this application, you can learn about obtaining a valid key here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key"

If I then replace the key with my own key, with the same referrers settings, it works..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: V3 doesn't require keys for most things. Take the key out and try it with just the sensor querystring.

Comment: I would remove the key but my maps page on day 1 alone pulled in 37,000 page loads. That's 12k over the courtesy limit. What is the limit for not using a key? I would guess less? I'm pretty certain they would stop serving me maps after so many consecutive days of pulling that kinda traffic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by simply generating a new browser key. I generated, threw it in the browser, the map loaded. Then I went in and copied my referrers over from the previous key. Saved. Refreshed. And it still worked. I honestly think it was a bug on Google's end and the day we were generating the original keys it was spitting out invalid keys.

Answer (score 22):

You are missing the `v=3` before your `key={yourkey}`

Like this:

```
maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key={your key}&sensor=false
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually you want the `Google Maps JavaScript API` to be enabled instead of `Google Maps API v3` because the former is what you are actually using here. The latter is now divided into iOS and Android BTW.

Also you need to add your reference into your server key.

If it is local, it should be something like:

`localhost/*`

Answer (score 4):

I think you must check the referrers. 
The given example on the API console site is:

```
Example: *.example.com/*. *One URL or pattern per line.*
```

Try to include the full referrer names without using wildcards. The wildcard usage seems a bit strange. More people struggle with that, see [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/NHDMRPYpdko) post. You can find a description of the possible whitelist configuration on the [Google APIs Console Help page](https://developers.google.com/console/help/#restrictingusage).

(You mentioned that your personal key has the same referrers as your company key. I wonder if this is possible as you could use different keys for the same app in this case.)

Comment: I am matching the referrers exactly across my two Projects (Dev & Prod). I've modified my referrers to include more pages (separated by new line) to look like:
  
*.example.com/* 
------
example.com/* 
------
www.example.com ------
www.example.com/* ------ I can't include exact matches because my URLS are dynamic based on the page your on. I would imagine any of our developers should be able to generate their own key and use it on our domain using the right referrer, as I did. So I don't think there should be any conflicts.

Comment: Sorry, I have no further idea. What happens if you leave the referres empty (only for a quick test of course)? What happens if you remove the referrers from your personal key - is the prod key starting to work in this case?

Comment: I logged into the company account and created a key with no referrers added and tested it. It didn't work either. It's almost like its generating an invalid key to be used with Google Maps v3. The error message does say it could be It's not a valid v3 key OR that the referrers are correct. It's really ticking me off though! Does google have a support email or phone number I could reach out to directly?

Comment: There is a "Send feedback" button on the "API Access" page but I am not sure if you get personal help. There is also a decription of the "Whitelisting by Host (Browser-embedded scripts)" configuration on the [APIs Console Help page](https://developers.google.com/console/help/#restrictingusage). Check your configuration angainst the possible host notations.

Answer (score 3):

I hit my head against the wall on this for a while. Including the version number, which the example does not do, fixed it for me.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=YOURKEY">`

^ That one has the `?v=3.exp` bit

Answer (score 2):

Under referrers, we had `*`. The fix was actually to leave it blank `` which means allow all.

Answer (score 2):

Add `v=3;` before your key.

```
maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?**v=3;**key={your key};sensor=false
```

Comment: This just makes the 'key' parameter invalid, which is the same as not having it at all. It'll make the map work, but give you this console warning "Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys". Not a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had a number of reports from clients about problems with Google maps on their sites. I checked and got "Invalid key" errors.

Strangely, Google used to give out keys with a space before and after the API key. In the past, when I left the spaces off, the key broke. It was frustrating to remember to leave those spaces.

Now, I `trim()` my current API Key (with or without spaces) before submitting it to Google Maps and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing locally, make sure to add your local ip to the server key:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

if you want the maps api to be available across the whole domain add this to the browser key:

```
*.mydomain.com/*
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have been getting the invalid key message too, and after trawling all round the web, have found what MY problem was. It may affect others too. It had nothing to do with the key.

I discovered that I had an error in the 'initialize' function (in my case a missing comma at the end of a line in the mapOptions). This arose because I added a new (last) line, and failed to put a comma at the end of the preceding one. A good argument for always having a comma, even on the last line.

I can now switch the invalid key message ON or OFF my removing/replacing that comma. I conclude that any error in the map related JS may give rise to it.

Answer (score 0):

Now adding a map from Google has become more problematic than it was before. On the page https://leafletjs.com/ you will find another more convenient library with maps.