# Google maps API key works on a site, but does not work on an other site though referer for the other site is added

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, key

I have a site using the javascript maps api and it works fine with an api key. I created a second site under a different domain and I want to use the same API key for that. I added the domain of the second site to the list of referers of the API key, so the referer list now has two entries: the domain of the first site and the domain of the second site. Yet the key refuses to work on the second site, while it's working fine on the first site.

This is the error I'm getting on the second site:

> Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site.

What causes this error if the key is working fine on the first site and I added the second site to the key's enabled referers?

Comment: [This any use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966668/the-key-provided-is-not-a-valid-google-api-key), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281897/google-maps-v3-api-key-invalid-but-my-personal-dev-key-works)?

Comment: Regarding the first one: it's not localhost, and I don't want to allow any referer to use my key. This defeats the purpose. As for the second: generating a new key for the second site doesn't work either.